# $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_n}}\leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{1+\lambda}}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ be positive numbers such that $x_1x_2...x_n=1$.

> For $n \geq 3$ and $0<\lambda\leq\frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2}$, prove that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_n}}\leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{1+\lambda}}$$

My initial thought:
What if I let $v_i=\lambda x_i$, so the given condition will become $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}v_i=\lambda^n$$ and $$\lambda=\left (\prod_{i=1}^{n}v_i\right)^{1/n}\leq \frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2}$$

$$\therefore \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_n}}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+v_i}}\leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{1+\lambda}}$$

But I have no idea how to proceed from here. Any alternative solutions/tricks/guidances are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For $n=3$ and $\lambda=\frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2}$ we obtain  known Vasc's inequality. In the general, by his HCF Theorem it's enough to prove your inequality for equality case of $n-1$ variables, which gives something very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The maximisers of $\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_i}}$ will be stationary points of the Lagrangian
$$
L(x_1, \cdots, x_n; \mu) = \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda x_i}} - \mu x_1 \cdots x_n
$$

Solving the corresponding system, you'll see that the maximizer will satisfy $x_1=x_2 = \cdots = x_n$, which means that all $x_i$'s must be one in order to maximise $f$. The proof is "complete" by noting that  $f(1,1,\cdots, 1) = \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{1+\lambda}}$.

Still needs to be addressed:

1. Using second order conditions to show that this single stationary point of the Lagrangian is indeed a maximiser.
2. Showing that the objective function does not extend to the boundary with a value greater than $f(1,\cdots,1)$, making the stationary point a global maximiser in $\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}$.

Comment: I don't want to waste 1 point for downvoting you, but this is not the solution.

Comment: @NN2 Even without wasting a point, it would be useful to ellaborate.

Comment: It is impossible to solve the system of equations $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = 0$!

Comment: @NN2 It is not... Every equation will be of the form $$2 \sqrt{1+\lambda x_i} = \frac{\mu}{x_i}$$
It is just a matter of using the restriction to get $\prod_{j\ne i} x_j = \frac{1}{x_i}$

Comment: But how you solve all $n$ cubic equations with the constraint $\prod x_i = 1$? It's impossible.

Comment: @NN2 I don't need to solve the cubics, I just need to show that they all have a single real root. Since all the equations will be the same cubic, all $x_i$'s must be equal.

Comment: Not sure, as the cubic equation may have 3 roots.

Comment: The conditions $\lambda, x_i >0$ guarantee a positive derivative and therefore a single real solution.

Comment: Ok, I see. But for your 2nd point, the objective function $L$ is not decreasing towards the boundaries. Take for example $x_1 = x_2  =...=x_{n-1} = \epsilon$ and $x_n = \epsilon^{-(n-1)}$, then $L$ reaches its maximum $$L \xrightarrow{\epsilon \to 0} RHS$$
if $\lambda = \frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2}$

Comment: @NN2 You are correct, I should rephrase it: it does not need to decrease towards the boundary, it is just that the boundary value must be smaller than $f(1,1, \cdots,1)$. As you mention, this is the reason for the condition $\lambda\leq \frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2}$.

Comment: @Yes. 
And now I think you are on the right track. Just some remaining points need to be solved.

Comment: @PierreCarre Let $n=3$,$\lambda=\frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2},$ $x_1=\frac{b}{a}$, $x_2=\frac{c}{b}$ and $x_3=\frac{a}{c}$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives. Thus, we need to prove that: $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{4a+5b}}\leq1.$ Now, try $a=b$ and $c\rightarrow0^+$, which says that your reasoning is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How does this invalidate my reasoning? The limit value, $\frac{13}{9}$, is smaller than $f(1,1,\cdots, 1)$, which is equal to $2$.

Comment: @PierreCarre It means $c\rightarrow0^+$ and after this $b\rightarrow0^+$. What do you say now?